# Can one be "convicted" if one has a strong opinion?

Tags: meaning, etymology, word-usage

Can "convicted" be used to qualify somebody who has a conviction (in the sense of strong opinion)? In that context it would be a close synonym of convinced or opinionated for example.

It possibly makes etymological sense but I don't know if it is (or has ever been) an accepted usage of that word in English.

Comment: I think it would be "Convictive". `He said it with such conviction. He was convictive`

Comment: Aside: Lots of people have been convicted (normal meaning) for having strong opinions :P

Comment: @James Webster (comment 1): If _convicted_ (adjective) were not obsolete, _convicted_ would relate to _convinced_ as _convictive_ does to _convincing_. The latter two adjectives necessarily accompany a demonstration (an attempt to convince, say) whereas 'convinced' doesn't - it refers to a person's belief system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Convicted* has been used in the sense of *convinced*.

> **†3.** To prove, establish by proof, as against assertions to the contrary. (= **convince** v. 5) (*Orig.* of things blamable.) *Obs.*
>   c1475  (▸?c1400)    *Apol. Lollard Doctr.* (1842) 3   If he be conuicted not to luf, ne to do þe office of Crist.
>   1558   Q. Kennedy *Compendius Tractiue* in D. Laing *Misc. Wodrow Soc.* (1844) I. 119   Thir twa argumentis..convictis the generale Counsalis to be the membir of the Congregatioun representand the universale Kirk.
>   1563   *2nd Tome Homelyes* Rebellion ii, in J. Griffiths *Two Bks. Homilies* (1859) ii. 565   Convicting such subjects..to be neither good subjects nor good men.
>   1593   R. Hooker *Of Lawes Eccl. Politie* iii. xi. 168   Imagining that these proofs will conuict a testament to haue that in it which other men can no where by reading find.
>   1656   J. Smith *Compl. Pract. Physick* 137   Cold water may be allowed to those are used to it, on the state and the matter being convicted.
>
> [OED]

I had thought that it appeared in Austen's writings too, but it is listed as now obsolete.

Comment: Obsolete it may be, but I have heard the word used in this context by born-again Christians who state they are "convicted of Christ" -- don't know if this a resurrection of the term, or they just want to make a special kind of emphasis, through use of the archaic.

Answer (score 0):

Use of *convicted* as a close synonym of convinced or opinionated is rare, but certainly not unknown.  For example, in 
*[The Gondoliers](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/808/808-h/808-h.htm#link2H_4_0001)*, as Grand Inquisitioner Don Alhambra del Bolero tries to overcome objections of Marco and Giuseppe Palmieri against one of them being King, the term is used in this sense, among others:

> `GIU.` Such a king would be a blessing to his people, and if   I were a king, that is the sort of king I would be.
>   `MAR.` And so would I!
>   `DON AL.`  Come, I'm glad to find your objections are not  insuperable.
>   `MAR.` and `GIU.`  Oh, they're not insuperable.
>   `GIANETTA` and `TESSA`  No, they're not insuperable.
>   `GIU.` Besides, we are open to conviction.
>   `GIA.` Yes; they are open to conviction.
>   `TESS.` Oh! they've often been convicted.

Here's an example of use in a [contemporary blog](http://thewacocampbellcrew.blogspot.com/):

> i think that most of you know by now that i am a person with strong convictions but as i get older and hopefully wiser, i am learning that i have often been convicted about the wrong things.

Comment: I am fairly sure that Gilbert and Sullivan meant *"Oh! they've often been convicted"* as a pun on the judicial meaning of *convicted,* and not as an example of the type the OP is looking for.

Comment: @PeterShor, yes, it's a pun that plays on two different meanings, as I implied via phrase “the term is used in this sense, among others”.

Comment: I am not sure how much confidence we can have in a quote from a random blog - I asked the original question because I heard someone use the word in a context that seemed odd.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a matter of connotation, as I have heard convicted used (rarely,) but with a sense that it differs from convinced as know differs from believe. Someone who's convinced can be convinced of something different, possibly, but to be convicted is to be, by implication, "locked in" to a stance (pun intended by me if not by earlier usage.)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As a newcomer you may be unaware that an answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. I recommend you [edit] your answer to provide evidence in support of your proposition - e.g. add some published **contemporary** examples of this usage. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)