# How did the relatively new usage of the word "convicted" to mean "committed" or "dedicated" come about?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, grammaticality

It seems to me that it is a back-construction of "conviction", in the sense of a firmly held belief or opinion, and is not a recognized word.

Comment: As I recall two people asked for specific quotations of this use of convicted. What happened to those comments?

Comment: I didn't see those requests for specific quotations. But the last few years I've seen it used mostly in the hip-hop community to mean dedicated or committed. On another forum someone asks what does "I am very convicted person" mean. One good answer there is that it means the person has strong beliefs (convictions) about his clause, which supports my idea that it is a back construction of (having) conviction.

Comment: "Convicted" has been used in a religious sense to mean "convinced" for as long as I can remember.

Comment: @Xanne - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125137/can-one-be-convicted-if-one-has-a-strong-opinion?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

**Convicted** in the sense of **convinced** shows up in Google NGram (search term: I am convicted or I am convicted that) in the last decade primarily in books on religious commitment--and in this 1742 book, *Joseph Andrews,* by Henry Fielding:

> “Yes, but, Joseph,” said she, a little softened by the compliment to
>   her learning, “If you had a value for me, you certainly would have
>   found some method of showing it me; for *I am convicted* you must see
>   the value I have for you. Yes, Joseph, my eyes, whether I would or no,
>   must have declared a passion I cannot conquer.—Oh! Joseph!"

Here are a couple of the recent examples:

> Hello Mr. Murphy. *I am convicted that* God has something far better for
>   us. (2011)
>
> *I am convicted that* in America today, there is a growing hunger for
>   something far, far deeper than the thousand channels of vapid
>   meaningless chatter on cable and on our electronic gadgetry

There is also this example from 1982:

> The Cognitive Developmental Psychology of James Mark Baldwin: Current
>   Theory and Research in Genetic Epistemology (1982)
>
> John M. Broughton, D. John Freeman-Moir
>
> Further *I am convicted that* this source and center exerts, in manifold
>   ways, an attraction, a valence, a drawing into itself of our hunger
>   for excellence of being.

It's a difficult usage to detect, as there are so many false positives and the search engine seems to assume that what was meant was "convinced" instead of "convicted."

I didn't find any hip-hop references.

If seems never to have been common; its recent use in books is in a religious or "value" contexts.  It seems to me to be an undesirable use.

Comment: I don't think I saw your quite good answer until just now. I think it's use in the hip-hop community is mostly in spoken form. I've seen it used in interviews on television, where someone is talking about a cause and says they are "convicted". It sounds particularly strange used that way because of the meaning of being found guilty of a crime.